# Do Growth plates determine height

Tags: exercise, growth, height

Having checked other `SE answers` and ongoing through one of the answers [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22498/can-i-increase-my-height-after-24), I got to know that fusion of growth plates determine the height.

Does that mean that someone's growth plates have not fused yet and there is a possibility for increment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diagnose, or validation that you will or won't grow in the future, is very difficult to make over the internet. I'd suggest going to your doctor, which for sure will forward you to a specialist. They can take x-rays, of your hand for example, to determine if your growth plates are fully connected yet and also calculate the height you may grow to in the future.